# Applying a formula to a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

TL;DR: Can someone help me edit the following VBA code to produce the formula below?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Table1[@[Device1]]/RC[-2] > 1.2, 3, Table1[@[Device1]]/RC[-2])"
```

This code produces the following formula:

```
=IF(Table1[@[Device1]]/R2 >1.2, 3, Table1[@[Device1]]/R2)
```

But I would like it to produce the following instead:

```
=IF(Table1[@[Device1]]/$R2 >1.2, 3, Table1[@[Device1]]/$R2)
```

Longer context:

I'm looking to apply 2 formulas to a variable range of cells. In the formulas, I'm using RC notation to refer to cells near where the formulas are entered, and my code so far will correctly produce the first set of formulas regardless of the size of data used. I'm running into trouble with the second formula, where the column of values produced by the first formula needs to be referred to in the second formula.

Using RC[-2] means that when I drag the formula sideways to fill in cells in the same row, the cell being referred to will slide over 1 every time when I want it to stay within the same column.

The second formula correctly refers to the cell in R2, but I want $R2 instead of R2 in the formula

[image]

Comment: Change `[-2]` to `18`.

Comment: Hello, instead of using the table as a reference, you could call the cell directly:

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Table1[@[Device1]]/RC2 > 1.2, 3, Table1[@[Device1]]/RC2)"